# HTTPoison post request

Tags: elixir

I'm using HTTPoison lib for a post request heres my method

```
def do_request(method, url, body \\ "", headers \\ [], options \\ []) do
  headers = [{"Authorization", "Bearer #{Application.get_env(:app, :access_token)}"}]

  case body do
    {:json, json} ->
    headers = [{"Content-Type", "application/json"} | headers]
    body = Poison.Encoder.encode json

    {:file, _path} -> true
    _ -> body = []
  end

  request!(method, url, body, headers, options) |> process_response
end
```

calling the method:

```
body = %{ "account_id" => "123456" }
do_request(:post, '/users/get_account', JSX.encode!(body))
```

but i'm getting

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
           (jsx) src/jsx_decoder.erl:234: :jsx_decoder.value/4
         (exjsx) lib/jsx.ex:15: JSX.decode!/2
     (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:413: HTTPoison.Base.response/6
```

any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Is that the whole stacktrace? No lines mentioned from `do_request` in your app?

Comment: I think you pasted wrong code fragment. You pasted only the fragment with encoding. The problem probably lies somewhere in `process_response` which tries to decode the request. Poison returns a struct and you need to call `result.body` to get the body from struct. I guess you didn't do that and passed entire structure to the encoder. But it is only my wild guess :)

Comment: I've often also seen this happen when process_response calls `Poison.decode!(body)` when you have made a bad request and so the response is some html text or another invalid json string. Like tkowal said, its a short in the dark without seeing your override for `process_response`